# Powershell - Get-Process's ProcessName is truncated on macOS

Tags: macos, powershell, truncation

I'm using Powershell 7.2.5 on macOS 12.5.
I had Google Chrome open and ran `Get-Process google*`, and got truncated ProcessName:

```
gps google*                    

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
      0     0.00     626.36   5,529.29   33973   1 Google Chrome
      0     0.00     124.94   2,870.73   33993   1 Google Chrome H
```

`Google Chrome H` should be `Google Chrome Helper` or something longer.

`gps | sort-object {$_.ProcessName.length}` showed that all processnames are truncated to 15 chars.

How do I make `Get-Process` output without truncation?

I read the help for `Get-Process` and tried to pipe the output to `Format-Custom` and `Format-List ProcessName -Force`, and none of these tricks worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is ***not* a formatting problem**:
At least up to the .NET version underlying PowerShell Core 7.3.0-preview.6, .NET , .NET 7.0.0-preview.6.22324.4, the **`.ProcessName` property value is limited to 15 chars**.

This is a **known problem**, and there is a known fix, but no one has stepped up to implement it yet - see [GitHub issue #52860](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/52860)

A - computationally expensive - **workaround** is to use a call to the native `ps` utility, via a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```
Get-Process google* | 
  Select-Object Id, 
                @{ n='ProcessName'; e={ Split-Path -Leaf (ps -p $_.Id -o comm=) }
```

Note: The above reports just the process ID and the (full) process name.

More work is needed if you want the same display columns as you would get by default, only with the full process names:

```
Get-Process google* | ForEach-Object {
  $copy = $_ | Select-Object *
  $copy.ProcessName = Split-Path -Leaf (ps -p $_.Id -o comm=)
  $copy.pstypenames.Insert(0, 'System.Diagnostics.Process')
  $copy
}
```